# Android Location Promixity Query

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an app, where I need to determine which sqlite rows are closest to me given my current lat/long. I have a table with lat and long columns, I'm just having a bit of trouble working out how to get ones that are closest based on my devices current location. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this kind of situations you can use the *Manhatten Distance*. Let's suppose your current position is:

```
myPosition_Lat = XX
myPosition_Long = YY
```

And, that you have an array with the all the coordinates (`all_stops[]`). You just have to go over all items in `all_stops[]` and calculate the distance to `myPosition`, and save the minimum distance this way:

```
distance = Math.abs(myPosition_Lat - the_Lat) + Math.abs(myPosition_Long – the_Long);
```

Here `the_Lat` and `the_Long` contain the latitude and longitud you are calculating with.